# Set Image in cardview from JSON response

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-cardview

I am trying to set text and image in my cardview depending on the JSON response I get. My json will contain this info:

```
{["name":"Store 1","wifi":true, ...]}
```

I am using a fragment,cardadapter, and a class for the items I can now parse the name and show on my cardview but now I want to show an wifi icon from my drawable file if the response for wifi is true and don't show the icon if it is false.

code for parsing data in my fragment:

```
 private void parseData(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
        StoreListCard storeListCard = new StoreListCard();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            //Parse name
            storeListCard.setName(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));


            if(json.getBoolean(Config.TAG_WIFI) == true){
                storeListCard.setWifi(json.getBoolean(Config.TAG_WIFI));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        storeListCards.add(storeListCard);
    }

}
```

StoreListCard.java:

```
public class StoreListCard {
    private String name;
    private Boolean wifi;

        public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Boolean getWifi() {
    return wifi;
}

public void setWifi(Boolean wifi) {
    this.wifi = wifi;
}
}
```

CardAdapter:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    List<StoreListCard> storeListCards;
    public CardAdapter(List<StoreListCard> storeListCards, Context context){
    super();
    //Getting all the information
    this.storeListCards = storeListCards;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.store_cardview, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    StoreListCard storeListCard =  storeListCards.get(position);
    holder.tvStoreName.setText(storeListCard.getName());

    //This part I am not sure
    holder.ivWifiIcon.setImageResource();
}

    @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return storeListCards.size();
}

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView tvStoreName;
    public ImageView ivWifiIcon;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvStoreName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStoreName);
        ivWifiIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivWifiIcon);

    }
}
}
```

xml(part for name and wifi):

```
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivWaitingIcon"
                android:background="@drawable/tool_wifi_icon_02"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ivWaitingIcon"
                android:id="@+id/ivWifiIcon"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvStoreName"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

I can now successfully get the name to show, but I am not sure how to display icon depending on the response

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya No, the image is from my drawable folder, the json I get only returns true or false. And i will show the image from my drawable folder if the response gives me true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside onBindViewHolder do like this

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

     StoreListCard storeListCard =  storeListCards.get(position);
     holder.tvStoreName.setText(storeListCard.getName());

       if (storeListCard.getWifi()){
             holder.ivWifiIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_wifie_icon);
        } else {
        holder.ivWifiIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.any_place_holder_icon);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private void parseData(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
        StoreListCard storeListCard = new StoreListCard();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            //Parse name
            storeListCard.setName(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
            storeListCard.setWifi(json.getBoolean(Config.TAG_WIFI));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        storeListCards.add(storeListCard);
    }

}
```

In card adapter class.

```
        @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    StoreListCard storeListCard =  storeListCards.get(position);
    holder.tvStoreName.setText(storeListCard.getName());
    if(storeListCard .getWifi())
    {
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + imageName, null, null)
    holder.ivWifiIcon.setImageResource(id);
    }
}
```